# C - Error while passing structure to threads

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

Here I have a `struct`

```
struct dotData{
    long x;
    long y;
};
```

Which I try to pass to multiple `threads`

```
void *find_z(void *thisdot)
{
    long z;
    struct dotData *data;
    *data = *((struct dotData*)(thisdot));
    z = data.x + data.y;
    printf("Here's our dot! %ld * %ld = %ld \n", data.x, data.y, z);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

From `main()` where I create a struct `thisdot`, which is passed as an argument to `find_z` every time its elements `x` and `y` are changed

```
int main()
{
.
.
.
    struct dotData thisdot;

    int NUM_THREADS;
    NUM_THREADS = N*M;
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            thisdot.x = x_dotBegin + x_interval*j;
            thisdot.y = y_dotBegin + y_interval*i;
            pthread_create(&threads[NUM_THREADS], NULL, find_z, &thisdot);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

However, during compilation I get an error in `z = data.x + data.y;`

```
error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union|
error: request for member ‘y’ in something not a structure or union|
```

How do I correctly pass this struct to threads?

Comment: `data->x` and `data->y` but you have undefined behaviour with `*data = ...`

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what the problem is. Data is not a structure and not a union. Data is a pointer. Handle it like a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `data` is a *pointer* to a structure, and for those you need to use the "arrow" operator `->`, like in `data->x`.

---

There is a worse problem though:

```
struct dotData *data;
*data = *((struct dotData*)(thisdot));
```

The pointer `data` doesn't point anywhere. Uninitialized local (non-static) variables will have an *indeterminate* value. To use a pointer you actually need to make it point somewhere.

Or, for a simple solution and the one I recommend, not use pointers at all:

```
struct dotData = *(struct dotData *) thisdot;
```

---

You also have *another* big problem, in how you pass data to the threads. All the threads will get the same pointer to the same structure. So the modifications you make in the thread-creation loop will be set for *all* the data in *all* the threads.

This can be solved by dynamically allocating the structure you pass to the threads. You can then just copy the pointer instead of copy the structure. And you must remember to `free` the data or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a pointer, so use `(*data).x` or `data->x`